# How to use Posterous API to 'scrape' my own site for contributor info, date info, and response info

Tags: python, api, posterous

As a college teacher in STEM, I like it when I can use technology to enhance the learning experience of my students, and I doubly like it when it allows me to introduce them to cool tech, too.

During the last year, I've had a couple classes make posts to a Posterous site (http://spectrawiki.posterous.com) and post comments to the posts of others.  This is required for the course, and I've be saddled with keeping track of class activity.

I'd hoped I could download site content in a way that gives me the data I need (who posted, when they posted, and if they posted an article or comment), but Posterous doesn't have this functionality.  A very responsive Posterous Tech suggested I look at the API.

But I'm not a coder.  I know enough about coding (HTML, PHP, matlab, python, R, Mathematica) to respect those who really know what they're doing.

So I ask the Stack Overflow community:  how could I hack together something (e.g., a python script) with the API to get the data I'm looking for (listed above)?  Are there any tutorials out there that would lead me through the steps of building a script?  I've never used an API before, so I don't really know where to begin.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

[Edit] **For Example**:  the Posterous API Reference has an example like this

```
 curl -X PUT --user you@example.com:password -d "api_token=<your token>" -d "post[title]=New Title" http://posterous.com/api/2/sites/12345/posts/6789
```

when it talks about the API being RESTful.  How can I modify this curl command to return some type of information about *my* Posterous site?  I can (probably) handle the authentication flags and that token flag.  But using the other flags, that's where I could use a pointer.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. The first five search results for "posterous api python example" are a good start as far as tools, and a couple of Python tutorials are the way to start to pickup the language. When you have more specific programming questions, as per the FAQ, come back and ask.

Comment: agf - Thanks for the quick response.  It is a broad question because I'm casting about for anything.  I've looked at the Posterous API Reference (http://posterous.com/api) which many of those sites refer to as documentation, but boy howdy is it not appropriate for folks like me.  So I guess I'd like pointers to HOWTOs that would get my legs under me.

Comment: Did you follow the links through to [Pyposterous](https://github.com/thomasw/pyposterous), a Python library for accessing the API? It looks [fairly well documented](http://thomasw.github.com/pyposterous/).

Comment: I was worried that it was a year old.  Many other posts seem to suggest that the API has been modified quite a bit recently.  That makes me cautious about pyposterous for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow-up, 5 December 2012:**  It looks like pyposterous no longer works.  My scripts fail and pyposterous fails its own unit tests.  Bummer.

====

Pyposterous did, indeed, give me the tools to answer my question, so I thought I'd share it here for others.  Here's the script I wrote:

```
import datetime
import pyposterous
from pyposterous import Cursor

api = pyposterous.API(username='[username]', password='[passwd]')

d=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%y%B%d-%H%M")
filename = 'report-posts-' + str(d) +'.txt' 
log=open(filename,'w')

for post in Cursor(method=api.read_posts, start_page=1, parameters={'hostname':'spectrawiki'}):
    try:
        print >> log,  "--------------------"
        print >> log, "%s, %s, %s" % (post.author, post.date, post.title)
    except AttributeError:
        pass # No comments
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
```

It's a crude script, but it gets the basic job done.